# Isomorphic group representations means isomorphic groups?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

a question just came across my mind, but I am not able to answer it. Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$. Let $G$ and $H$ be to finite groups. Are there theorems that say:
If $\operatorname{Rep}_K(G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Rep}_K(H)$ (as categories), then $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ as groups?

Maybe even an equivalence of categories is enough? Or just considering finite dimensional representations?
You can add whatever you want to make this true.

Thx!

Comment: Isomorphisms of these categories (purely as categories) can only distinguish the number of irreps (i.e. the number of conjugacy classes), since the category is semisimple with that number of simple objects.

Comment: (and with 1-dimensional spaces of endomorphisms of the simple objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tannaka duality gives an answer to your question if you suppose that they are isomorphic as tensor categories.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality

Comment: I think it can be shown more directly for finite groups (along the lines: Isomorphic as tensor categories => same group-like elements => isomorphic groups).